# Getting error Attempted to start a foreground service (xxx) with a broken notification (no icon: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null ---

Tags: android-service, android-notifications

I do not understand this error message in Android Studio. Looking at the source code this error is caused by the small icon being null. But I set the icon (both large and small) and the notification **is** present WITH my icon. I even used the Asset Studio to create this icon specifically for notifications.

There are a lot of other posts on this topic but they all seem related to those trying to HIDE the notification in some way. I want it so that my service is not killed by Android!

Here is the full error

```
Attempted to start a foreground service (ComponentInfo{com.lni.pchademophg/com.lni.pchademophg.BaseManager}) with a broken notification (no icon: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE secFlags=0x0 secPriority=0))
```

Why the error? ( I guess I shouldn't complain, everything works as I need it to work ... at least it appears so, but the error is unsettling and I would like to understand it.)
This error is occurring on a 6.0.1 device (have not tried a 10 yet)

Here is my code which is in the 'onsStartCommand()' method of the service:

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        createNotificationChannel();

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context, mChannel.getId())
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentText("Pcha Personal Health Gateway")
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_stat_name))
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
    else
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "BtleScanChannel");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        {
            notificationBuilder.setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        }
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Pcha Personal Health Gateway")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_stat_name));
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    return START_STICKY; 
}
```

Any ideas? What are the consequences?

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. However, on the plus side the app seems to work as it should and if it weren't for the log message I would not know. But one of these days it will probably bite me in the butt.

Comment: where it might bite you is if you want to add a custom sound... which I have attempted to do and had it working for a while but now I get that message and the sound=null part is weird since I set the sound. My notif otherwise appears as expected just like you.

Comment: Good to know. But I don't know if I still get that. I have had many AS, gradle, and OS levels/build tool updates since then. Will need to check

Comment: I am also facing this issue but only after phone boot up. I am running a background service on phone boot. Now if I am sending a notification and if I am clicking on it I am getting this error.(On clicking notification a modal should show that is not showing). But once app is opened manually then everything works fine.

Comment: @VinayKharayat I have not been getting that error message for quite a while. Can't say when it vanished. I did change the icon ot this, however, setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round) but I don't think I did that for trying to correct the error.